# Running code from a specific thread in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread

I have a function like this:

```
func foobar() {
  let targetThread = Thread.current

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
      // Code I need to run on the main thread
    }, completion: {
      // Code I want to run on targetThread -- HOW?
    }
  }
}
```

How do I execute code from `targetThread`? Thanks.

Comment: it will be better you create a new thread instead using currently running thread. and keep an access to it outside the method, and start it when you call this method. class var current: Thread
Returns the thread object representing the current thread of execution.

Comment: Why do you need to run code on a specific thread? You shouldn't have to and this is discouraged. You probably want to `DispatchQueue.global().async` in the completion block and run the code there, but let us know why you want the code to run on a target thread?

Comment: It's very common to want to call delegates on the same thread that they called on. Unfortunately gcd doesn't really support that. NSObject's performSelector:onThread can be used, but it's not a very clean API. I've seen programs have their own performBlock:onThread method that uses performSelector:onThread.

Answer (score 6):

`DispatchQueue`s are not threads.  You'll note there is no way to get the current `DispatchQueue` the way you can get the current thread.  If you just want to run code somewhere that isn't the main thread, you can use:

`DispatchQueue.global().async { ... }`

If you really want to target your specific thread, you have two choices.

The first is you can use `NSObject`'s [`perform(_:on:with:waitUntilDone:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1414476-perform) (or one of the related methods) and pass the `NSThread` you've gotten.  There isn't enough context in your question to say if this will work for you or to give an example, but you can search.

The second is to re-work your code that is starting all of this to use an `NSOperationQueue`, so `foobar()` would be run in an operation on the `NSOperationQueue` and then in your completion for the animation, you'd schedule another `NSOperation` to run on the same Operation Queue.  You could also do this using dispatch queues directly: i.e. create your own dispatch queue, dispatch foobar, then dispatch back to your queue from main when the animation completes.